# How do I give a player a message when their hunger is low?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want players to get the message "Your hunger is low: eat something." when their hunger is at three bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set up a scoreboard to track their hunger: `/scoreboard objectives add hunger food`, and then in a repeating, always active command block (placed in a spawn chunk so its always loaded) put `execute as @a[scores={hunger=6}] run say I need to eat something`. I assumed that by 3 bars you meant three out of the ten, which is actually 6 hunger points, and that you want the message to play just once, not every tick that they have 6 or less food points, because that would probably be annoying. I also assumed it would be okay if the message is from the first person, but if it's not I can try to figure out how to use `tellraw` selectors. This is a 1.14 specific answer but should also work in 1.13 too.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me but when I try it with title like this: execute as @a[scores={hunger=6}] run title @a title {"text":"I need to eat something"}  minecraft is spamming the messages

Comment: In a command block chained to that initial one give the player a scoreboard tag of "hungry" (or something similar). Then, in another always active command block, remove the hungry tag from all players with 7 or more hunger score `{hunger=7..}`. Finally, make sure the original command block executes as those with a hunger score of 6 and without the hungry tag. This will cause the message to be created once, then the tag hungry is added, and it doesn't give them the message anymore. When they eat, the tag is removed so when their hunger falls back below 6 it shows the message again.